# Is Django Template legacy?

Tags: django, django-templates

Django, as a backend framework, has the main purpose of returning JSON-format data to the frontend developer. So why do we need templates to render HTML with Django?

We can use React for the frontend and Django for the backend to provide data via API.

The problem is: is this technology a legacy? Does anyone or the company use templates to render the frontend using Django for now in a real project?

Also, I am a noob in backend development, so can anybody tell me what backend developers work on exactly except create APIs and make databases?

Comment: A backend does not per se returns JSON blobs, PHP for example typically also renders HTML pages. With Angular/React/Vue/... one can indeed serve JSON blobs, but a lot of sites are just simple HTML served by the server. This often is also actually simpler.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is: is this technology a legacy? Does anyone or the company use templates to render the frontend using Django for now in a real project?

**Yes**, a lot. Rendering the site with JavaScript with some tool like Angular, React and Vue indeed gains momentum nowadays, but it is not ubiquitous. There are several reasons for this. One is that JavaScript is a language that can not be checked very rigorously. There has been some advancement on this with TypeScript and functional programming techniques (for example monads) or even PureScript. There is also some discussion whether react technology is against how webpages were designed to work.

> "The web is a streaming thing by default. You go to a page and it serves HTML. You'll start seeing it as it's downloaded. Same with images, video...You can do something with just a little bit of the response." - Jake Archibald

This claim says that normally the page received HTML and can immediately start rendering content, not first load some library that will make requests to render content. The quote of Arcibald is of course just one person's opinion, but even if a new paradigm for the Internet is advisable, it will take *a lot* of time before all heads are turned.

Very often a generated HTML page can be cached, not only by the server, but also by the client by injecting the caching policy in the header. For a JavaScript website, it will fetch the data through API calls, these might be cached by the backend. Caching these by the client is at least a lot more complicated.

There are other problems that ship with these platforms. Often they are quite "fat" require loading a lot of libraries, are not very conservative with bandwidth nor RAM or processing power. It also moves logic to the frontend, and while a lot of progress has been made, it turns out, it is still quite hard to get a nice looking frontend through react.

The fact that the there was first angular, then react and now Vue also means currently there is no de-facto standard on how to do this, and thus resources invested in angular when Angular was very popular in 2018, are now likely not very relevant anymore. The fact that it is unknown if react or vue are there to stay, means it is a risk to build tooling on top of that. This is the so-called [*Lindy-effect* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindy_effect): the longer technology stays, the more likely it has a long future ahead. Backend-rendering has proven that it works, so it is likely that it will remain here for a certain time.

Finally it also introduces an extra part to "glue" together, and this means that if the front-end developer accesses the APIs in an inefficient manner, or the API provides data in such way that the frontend needs to make a lot of requests, the site can load quite slowly.

While rendering pages by the backend often indeed is not very interactive, at least it can last a long time. By working mainly with HTML, even very old browsers, or console-based browsers like *Lynx* still can render these. Django's own admin mini-site is not rendered through react, vue, or some other JavaScript library, but by HTML rendered by Django.

There are indeed backends that focus entirely on building an API and then let some JavaScript library do the rendering, a lot of sites use rendering by the backend, for example like WordPress and most of the sites build on top of PHP.